# bitwise operators in lua to create string

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation, wireshark-dissector

New user to LUA creating a protocol dissector for Wireshark.

referring to [Lua - Bitwise Logical Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977654/lua-bitwise-logical-operations#),

I need a function in Lua to create a string based on a converted hex value:

```
local function HexToCircuitID(val)
    -- input: 0x9D81
    -- output: "630.1.01"
    local e = ((val >> 4) & 0x3) + 1
    local f = val & 0xF
    local g = val >> 6
    return string.format("%d.%d.%02d",e,f,g)
end
```

the interpreter has a problem with "unexpected symbol near '>' " for the first line with the right-shift operator.

Also, I'm not sure the string format function will operate the same as in C (new to Lua).  This function is to create a ProtoField that appears as:

```
CircuitId: 630.1.01
```

where the actual value of the field is 0x9D81.

Comment: did you check the lua version? the answers from that question you linked explain that 5.2 and earlier lua versions do not have bitwise operators just a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bit.rshift(x, n)` to right shift and `bit.band(x1[,x2...])` to &.

The function then becomes:

```
local function HexToCircuitID(val)
    -- input: 0x9D81
    -- output: "630.1.01"
    local e = bit.band(bit.rshift(val, 4), 0x3) + 1
    local f = bit.band(val, 0xF)
    local g = bit.rshift(val, 6)

    --return string.format("%d.%d.%02d",e,f,g)
    return string.format("%d.%d.%02d",g,f,e)
end
```

To get the order right I had to change e,f,g to g,f,e.

This will work in the latest version of Wireshark, which uses Lua 5.2. As Nifim mentioned, you have to use the bit library rather than bitwise operators, as they were introduced in Lua 5.3.

Comment: And FYI, some previous discussions about updating to Lua 5.3 and beyond can be found here: https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201807/msg00040.html, and even earlier at https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201608/msg00082.html and even more information in the Bug 10881 report: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10881